# Infinite System of Stochastic Ordinary Differential Equations Coupled by Infinite Graphs

Tags: differential-equations, reference-request, pr.probability

$\ \ \ $ In *Time Evolution of Infinite Anharmonic Systems*,
Lanford,Lebowitz and Lieb, roughly speaking, proved that for some families of functions $F_v$ $(v\in\mathbb Z^d)$ 
and a large set of initial condition, there exist a unique solution defined on a non-degenerated interval
$[0,T]$ for the infinite system 
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
    \frac{d}{dt}q_v(t)&=&p_v(t)\\
    \frac{d}{dt}p_v(t)&=&F_v(X(t))\\
    X(0)&=&X_0,
\end{array}
\right.
$$
where $X_0$ and $X(t)$ belongs to some Banach space contained in $(\mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R^n)^{\mathbb Z^d}$
and as mentioned before $v\in\mathbb Z^d$.

$\ \ \ $ Although the authors do not mention, their results can be generalized for any infinite uniformly bounded degree graph. But a more interesting generalization, would be made by considering 
the stochastic case. Because it seems to be physically relevant to consider that the forces in each vertex of
the graph are not completely known, due some random perturbations.

$\ \ \ $ Could you help me to find a reference where this kind of model is considered ?